# Using the word pathos as a noun?

Tags: word-choice

I've written a short story for my English class. One sentence I wrote begins with:

> A fearful pathos overwhelmed [her]...

Someone reading the story very annoyingly marked the word "pathos" with a bunch of question marks:

**?p¿athos??**

And since they are an English teacher, I was wondering whether the above sentence actually makes sense.

I used it as to mean she had a surge of emotion (of the scared kind). To me it sounds pretty natural, but I'm not sure if the word "pathos" can be used in this way.

Not to mention my use of the word fearful. Surely you can use it to mean "related to fear", right?

Comment: "Pathos" *is* a noun...

Comment: How can pathos  be fearful?

Comment: Yes, _pathos_ is a noun, but it refers to the effect of a situation on _other_ people, not on the person in that situation. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pathos. So you can't use it for someone's emotion of fear.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want to convey, but you could flip the modifier and the modified around and say "A pathetic fear overwhelmed her," which would (to my ear) be more idiomatic.

Comment: A *sense of pathos* overwhelmed her.